# Node.js Express, router, optimal param as extension

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, express, routes

My first Node.js Express app. In the routes, I'm having a route called **/info**, which renders an info page template.

app.js:

```
app.use('/info', info);
```

info.js:

```
// routes to /info, and should also handle /info.json
router.get('/', function(req, res) { //... });
```

I also want to be able to use the same function above, to use an optimal parameter **.json**, to render json content instead - **/info.json**.

I've been trying with regex but I can't get it to work. I can only manage to do: **/info/.json**

Is it possible to do this using the same function?

Comment: Do you want `/` and `/info` to use the same router?

Comment: No, I want /info and /info.json to use the same router.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the [content-negotiation](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.format) feature of express. First, declare your route like:

```
app.get('/info(.json)?', info);
```

Then in info (taken from link above):

```
res.format({
  'text/html': function(){
    res.send('hey');
  },

  'application/json': function(){
    res.send({ message: 'hey' });
  }
});
```

**EDIT**: using a single route with regex

Answer (score 1):

With using `app.use('/info', info);` you're saying route the `info` path. That's why you're getting `/info/.json` so you're going to have change how you have things set up for this to work.

Instead of `module.exports = router;` in your info.js, you'll want to do something like this:

```
module.exports = function(req, res) {
   if(req.isJSON) {

   } else {

   }
}
```

In your app.js you'll have some route middleware to flag the request as `.json`:

```
app.use('*.json', function() {
  req.isJSON = true;
  next();
});

app.get('/info', info);
app.get('/info.json', info);
```